# 2 sets of 3 cards, 5 known cards, 1 unknown - What is the unknown card?

Tags: mathematics, pattern

There are two sets. The last card of the second is unknown.
The first set is 5, 6, and 10. The second set is 7, 2, and ?

What card is the question mark hiding?

I'm too awful at math to figure it out myself. Just wanna know the answer so I can go "ooooh. I get it"

Comment: This is basically a guess what I'm thinking problem, anything could work with some explanation

Comment: I think it's meant to be like "If 5 and 6 equals 10, what does 7 and 2 equal?"

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: @Oliver that's still broad

Comment: I think it's 3 because we have (10,7), (5,2) and so (6,3) and no other combo works.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is an attempt to illustrate how broad the question is to show why this is a bad question.

Here we go, in no particular order.

1.

> $5+6-1=10$, so $7+2-1=8$

2.

> $\frac{5\times6}{3}=10$, so $\frac{7\times2}{3}=4.666...$

3.

> $|5-6|\times10=10$, so $|7-2|\times10=50$

4.

> $5-6+11=10$, so $7-2+11=16$

5.

> $5.6+4.4=10$, so $7.2+4.4=11.6$

6.

> $\frac{5^6\times2}{9375}=10$, so $\frac{7^2\times2}{9375}=0.01045333...$

The last one is ridiculous on purpose - it serves to illustrate the point that almost anything could be an answer.